# Как удалить символы переноса строк, стоящие перед определёнными символами

Tags: linux, sed, grep

Есть строки вида:

```
A qwe1
B qwe2
C qwe3 лллл
лллл
лл
D qwe4
```

Нужно удалить символа переноса строк с предыдущей строки, если текущая строка начинается не с [a-zA-Z]

Т.е. на выходе должно получится:

```
A qwe1
B qwe2
C qwe3 лллл    лллл    лл
D qwe4
```

Вижу такой вариант:

```
grep -vn '^[a-zA-Z]' $inFile | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -nr | while read -r line
do
rn=$((line-1))
sed -i "N;${rn}s/\n//g" $inFile | echo $rn
done
```

- получаю номера строк, которые начинаются не с [a-zA-Z]
- сортирую в обратном порядке, чтобы после удаления переноса строки не сбился порядок строк
- вычитаю из нее 1, чтобы получить номер предыдущей строки
- с помощью sed удаляю символ \n в определенной строке

Но у меня символ удаляется только для одной строки:

```
A qwe1
B qwe2
C qwe3 лллл    лллл
лл
D qwe4
```

Подскажите, из-за чего это?

upd:

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later         <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.


./start.sh
A qwe1
B qwe2
C qwe3 лллл
лллл
лл
D qwe4
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin sed -i ':a;N;/\n[^a-zA-Z]/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' $inFile ничего не делает с файлом, нет опечаток в скрипте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно обойтись одним лишь, например, [интерпретатором *sed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36230031/4827341):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n[^a-zA-Z]/s/\n/ /;ta' файл
```

конечено, это сработает только в реализации интерпретатора от проекта *gnu*.

- `:a` — это метка с именем `a`
- `N` — добавить символ новой строки в конец *pattern space*, затем дописать туда же следующую строку из входного потока
- `/\n[^a-zA-Z]/s/\n/ /` — общий синтаксис: `/шаблон/команда`. `команда` будет выполена для строк, соответствующих `шаблону`

  - `\n[^a-zA-Z]` — составной шаблон: символ перевода строки, затем символ, соответствующий шаблону `[^a-zA-Z]`, т.е., «не буква латинского алфавита»
  - `s/\n/ /` — команда `s`, заменяющая символ перевода строки на пробел
- `ta` — условный переход (если последняя выполненная команад `s` осуществила замену) на метку `a`

---

предыдущий предложенный мной вариант:

```
sed ':a;N;/\n[^a-zA-Z]/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' файл
```

включал ещё две команды, которые, по размышлении, я решил убрать как излишние:

- `P` — в данном случае выведет *pattern space*
- `D` — в данном случае очистит *pattern space* и запустит нормальный новый цикл (обработку следующей строки из входного потока).

---

а в чём же у вас ошибка? вот здесь:

```
sed "N;${rn}s/\n//g"
```

при обработке очередной строки сначала будет прочитана следующая (благодаря `N`), и только затем будет обработано условие `номер-строки команда` (пробел тут только для наглядности, обычно его не используют в этом месте, хотя и с пробелом получается вполне корректная конструкция).

к чему приведёт такая логика для вашего случая и в том цикле, когда в `$nr` будет `4`? программа для интерпретатора будет выглядеть так: `N;4s/\n//g`

1. начнётся с обработки строки номер 1. сразу же будет (благодаря `N`) считана и следующая за ней, условие не выполняется (строка имеет номер 1, это не совпадает с указанной цифрой `4`).
2. дальше будет обработана строка 3. сразу же будет прочитана и следующая за ней. но условие опять не выполнится: строка имеет номер 3, и это опять не совпадает с указанной цифрой `4`
3. дальше будет обработана строка 5. будет считана и следующая за ней, но, понятно, никаких замен произведено не будет.
4. файл кончился. замен не было.

как исправить именно ваш (довольно длинный и медленный) вариант? например, можно команду `N` переместить внутрь блока с командой `s`. да и модификатор `g` можно убрать — он тут излишен:

```
sed "${rn}{N;s/\n//}"
```

строки теперь будут читаться последовательно, без «пропусков». дополнительная строка будет считана только один раз — когда будет обрабатываться строка с номером, который будет подставлен из переменной оболочки `${rn}`.

Comment: почему то ваш короткий вариант у меня не работает(т.е. в файле ничего не меняется, с ключом -i тоже, с перенаправлением вывода в другой файл тоже, скрипт скопировал один в один), версию добавил в топик. Как и что нужно проверить, чтобы понять что именно не так?

Comment: версия 4.2.2? это в [jessie, например, такая была](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=sed&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all). запустил в докере jessie, отлично sed работает: `$ echo -e 'z\n1\n2'` выводит три строки, а `$ echo -e 'z\n1\n2' | sed ':a;N;/\n[^a-zA-Z]/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D'` — собирает в одну: `z 1 2`

Comment: @masterok23, разобрались, что было «не так»?

Comment: да, спасибо! У меня кодировка файла была win 1251, поменял на UTF-8 - все работает

Comment: @masterok23, кстати, поразмышлял над тем примером, на который я привёл ссылку. пожалуй, его даже стоит сократить, убрав последние две команды (`P` и `D`): `':a;N;/\n[^a-zA-Z]/s/\n/ /;ta'`. у меня на примерах нет отличия в работе.